# Upload 2 excel File using PHP in codeigniter via PHPSpreadsheet

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpspreadsheet

Im trying to read 2 excel file and save in db.. Im using PHPSpreadSheet to read the excel file.

Manage to insert the 1st file but unable to insert both files.

```
public function import_excel_files()
{
    $this->load->helper('url_helper');
    $this->load->model('model_finance');

    //upload daily collection file
    $file_mimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');

    if(isset($_FILES['upload_file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['upload_file']['type'], $file_mimes))
    {
        $arr_file = explode('.', $_FILES['upload_file']['name']);
        $extension = end($arr_file);

        if('csv' == $extension)
        {
            $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Csv();
        }
        else
        {
            $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
        }
        $spreadsheet = $reader->load($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']);
        $sheetData = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();

        // this function is to insert daily collection to db
        $this->model_finance->set_daily_collection($sheetData);

    }

    //upload daily sales file
    $file_mimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');

    if(isset($_FILES['upload_file_PBB']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['upload_file_PBB']['type'], $file_mimes))
    {
        $arr_file = explode('.', $_FILES['upload_file_PBB']['name']);
        $extension = end($arr_file);

        if('csv' == $extension)
        {
            $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Csv();
        }
        else
        {
            $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
        }
        $spreadsheet = $reader->load($_FILES['upload_file_PBB']['tmp_name']);
        $sheetData = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();

        // this function is to insert daily sales to db
        $this->model_finance->set_daily_sales($sheetData);

    }

    $this->load->view('pages/fin_matchpbb');
}
```

I expect both excel file upload and insert in db but now.. only the 1st file successfully insert to db.. the second file failed. I'm not sure why.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to to loop on $_FILES like below mentioned code

```
if ($_FILES['upload']) {
$file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['ufile']);
foreach ($file_ary as $file) {
    print 'File Name: ' . $file['name'];
    print 'File Type: ' . $file['type'];
    print 'File Size: ' . $file['size'];
}
```

}